# Strange Nginx Redirects to Foreign Servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm seeing some strange redirects in a Rails app, instead of a redirect to /login, there are one-off requests with redirects like:

- Redirected to https://www.group-ib.ru/login
- Redirected to https://buybestbiz.net/login
- Redirected to https://swipe.bz/login
- Redirected to https://blackpass.cc/login

I'm not sure how these foreign servers are landing there. I don't see how it can be a hack in my app code, because these are single random instances out of thousands happening in an hour.

I suspect it has something to do with the Nginx config.

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
}
```

```

What am I missing here?